# HTML5 audio tag is not working in Android

Tags: android, cordova

I have created a sample phone gap application for android ics . And the index.html has an audio tag like this.

```
<audio id="player1" controls preload><source src="media/track1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" /></audio>
```

I am not able to play the audio at all. I saw the stack overflow posts everywhere it's mentioned that the audio tag will work fine after froyo release. But, i am testing it in gingerbeard and in ICS and it's not working anywwhere.

Comment: See here what the browser supports: http://html5test.com/compare/browser/android40.html

Comment: @NicholasAlbion: HTC wildfires and HTC one V. Browser is Default android browser

Comment: Note that the default browser on HTC phones (maybe all Androids?) is _not_ Chrome.  Chrome supports PCM, AAC, Ogg and WebM, the default browser does not.

Comment: @NicholasAlbion: ok.Sorry, i forgot to mention that i am using an webview to see the html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTML5 Audio support is not consistent across different devices/OSes due to codec licensing issues and OS implementation/support.  If you are just playing MP3 files, you can reliably handle those by using PhoneGap's [Media](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#Media) class, which will provide consistent and reliable audio programming on all platforms.

If you want the ability to preload audio and have more advanced scenarios like polyphony or layering (like video game effects), you can use the [LowLatencyAudio](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LowLatencyAudio) PhoneGap native plugin.

Answer (score 6):

Super late to this but `type="audio/mp3"` is wrong - it should be `type="audio/mpeg"`

With that being said, Android is still terrible at playing HTML5 audio - you're required to reset the `src` attribute before playing sounds (or they'll only play once) and it's not tolerant of multiple file types (required for other browsers). Nor do they support the WebAudioAPI

Answer (score 2):

According to [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/android40.html) Android 4 only supports mp3 in the audio tag.

Comment: You may try use "controls" attribute the full way: controls="controls"

Comment: The mp3 you are playing is in the Android SD card, or hosted somewhere else ?

Comment: Then referring theese file is propably wrong. Read more about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209469/storing-android-application-data-on-sd-card

Answer (score 2):

Wish I answered with some findings earlier.

The following seem to work for me. Android seems very anal about which source comes first. So I had the "mp3" source as on the third line and moved it up so it works for sure now. The controls=controls is because without it IE 11 did not seem to work on regular PC. My thoughts on the matter. Had to make the copy in ogg for Firefox to recognize it.

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="/somefile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
<source src="/somefile.ogg" type="audio/ogg">   
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</source></audio>
```

Comment: Hi @moises,   
there is issue with above code.
It gives error for me as
<source src="audios/Ganna/songs.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">[ERROR ->]</source>
IT should be Like this-

Comment: Just remove </source> from last.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path to your mp3 is incorrect. If this file is on the SD card the path would be something like:

```
file:///sdcard/media/track1.mp3
```

Comment: But i am using an html tag. So will this work.<audio id="player1" controls preload><source src="file:///sdcard/media/track1.mp3
" type="audio/mp3" /></audio>

Comment: @karthick give it a try. The current path you've given your audio tag won't work if the audio file is on the SD card. That I know for sure.