# Visual Studio CTP2 multi-device hybrid app no sound

Tags: android, html, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I'm building a multi-device hybrid app with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722381.aspx) Visual Studio plugin. In my html file i use the html5 audio tag. This does only work with online mp3 files, not with offline mp3 files.
Is it possible that audio isn't supported in the multi-device hybrid apps plugin? Or is it just me doing something wrong? I'm testing it on a Nexus 5.

Here is the HTML that I'm using.

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio controls>
    <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Thanks

Comment: The audio specification is part of HTML5 and is not related to the plugin or Visual Studio. That being said, there have been issues and multiple threads on playing audio files on Android devices. These can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142084/html5-audio-tag-is-not-working-in-android) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515699/play-sound-on-phonegap-app-for-android).

Comment: I was able to get it working using the Media plugin for cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved. The solution is to use the [Cordova media plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova_media_media.md.html) to play audio files on the Android device.