# Streaming with HTML5 in Android

Tags: android, html, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I want to make a streaming with HTML5, in desktop works fine, but in android dont work, only work with local files on my server ".mp3", but with the code attached only works on my desktop, but not in android, any ideas? Thanks

```
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="http://radio3.oceanofm.com:8010/;" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="http://radio3.oceanofm.com:8010/;" type="audio/mpeg">
<source src="http://radio3.oceanofm.com:8010/;" type="audio/wav">
<source src="http://radio3.oceanofm.com:8010/;" type="audio/mp3">
I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5.
</audio>​
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this post: [HTML5 audio tag is not working in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142084/html5-audio-tag-is-not-working-in-android) , it seems that there can be many causes for your problem. Have you already checked those?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was watching this link and researching and giving me the error in android only with external url is "MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED" local files but does not happen. The content type of the URL is "audio / mpeg" I do not understand it happen!