# why doesnt work audio on android browser?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, android-browser

I am using audio tag. This works chrome, edge and ie. But doesn't work on android browser. what should I do?

```js
document.getElementById('my_audio').play();
```

```html
<audio id="my_audio" src="pages/alert.mp3">
```

Comment: Always first check compatibility. What version of browser you use? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#browser_compatibility

Comment: I am using Samsung internet v13.0.2.9. I see it supports audio tag.

Comment: Is your source downloaded?

Comment: I can listen to the file when I view it with view-resurce.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 audio tag is not working in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142084/html5-audio-tag-is-not-working-in-android)

Comment: Similar question but dont answer for me. I try all answer

Comment: Try with `<source ` tag instead of `src` tag

Comment: sorry, I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not enough code to recreate or understand your problem. Is your `.play();` command inside some function or it just runs when `<script>` is being processed? If not run by a function then you might be trying to do auto-play (which is not allowed, especially not on mobile browsers).