# Where is my sdcard location on 4.4.2?

Tags: android

On Android 4.4.2 `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` returns `/storage/emulated/0` but this path does not exist on my Nexus5 Android 4.4.2. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` worked up until Android 4.4.2.

How can I get the `/sdcard` path on Android 4.4.2?

Comment: The Nexus 5 has never run Android 4.2. How have you gotten Android 4.2 on your Nexus 5?

Comment: I'm assuming he meant KitKat Android 4.4.2

Comment: @Stephan Branczyk Yes, updated my question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> This path does not exist on my Nexus5 Android 4.4.2.

Yes, it does, for your process at runtime.

For example, [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/Download) downloads a file to `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`. If you log the location at runtime, when running it on a Nexus 5, it is reported as `/storage/emulated/0/Download`. And the download succeeds.

If you are looking for `/storage/emulated/0` via DDMS or **`adb shell`**, you will not find it. For those tools, default external storage is `/mnt/shell/emulated/0`. Hence, the downloaded file from the above sample appears in the `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/Download` directory.

AFAIK, the difference is tied to providing separate external storage to secondary accounts.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new:-) Also I was looking in wrong corner because of my wrong assumption...

Comment: I tried your code and the setDestinationInExternalPublicDir did not work on Samsung Galaxy S3 device. any idea?

Comment: "If you log the location at runtime, when running it on a Nexus 5, it is reported as /storage/emulated/0/Download". When you say *log*, do you mean using `Log.d()` or similar and launching the app from an IDE like Android Studio so you can view the log output? Or how do you view the log output?

Comment: @LarsH: "When you say log, do you mean using Log.d()..." -- yes.

Comment: So, if I wanna read and write files onto my nexus 5 during runtime, I need the /storage/emulated/... path and when trying to load the files from the phone to my PC, I will need the /mnt/shell/... path? Is that right?

Comment: @keinabel: it depends on the version of Android that your device runs.

Comment: @CommonsWare 6.0.1

Answer (score 2):

The [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) documentation says to use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) (as you are already correctly using).  This function is available on all versions of Android.

Are you seeing it return a path that isn't actually available on a 4.2 device?

Please note (from [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)):

> Applications should not directly use this top-level directory, in order to avoid polluting the user's root namespace. Any files that are private to the application should be placed in a directory returned by Context.getExternalFilesDir, which the system will take care of deleting if the application is uninstalled. Other shared files should be placed in one of the directories returned by getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String).
>
> Writing to this path requires the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and starting in read access requires the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, which is automatically granted if you hold the write permission.
>
> Starting in KITKAT, if your application only needs to store internal data, consider using getExternalFilesDir(String) or getExternalCacheDir(), which require no permissions to read or write.

Comment: Yes /storage/emulated/0 is not available on Nexus5, even though the function returns it.

Comment: This is the most fractured feature of Android I've ever seen.  Broken two of my apps from version 2.x to 4.x.

Comment: @NPike getExternalCacheDir() and getExternalFilesDir(String) has the same problem.

Comment: @Powder366, Yes, Pedantic found the solution, he just wasn't sure of the Android version you were using. Click on the link he found. Read everything after "Starting in KITKAT..." and use the code sample after that paragraph to see how external storage is monitored.

Comment: I didn't add a link, lol.  No, I haven't found a consistent solution that ranges from 2.x to 4.x.  I have some users with phones that do not return a folder for external storage.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes /storage/emulated/0 can be written to, but reads fail... so tests for "writability" are not sufficient. This is such an annoying problem, I have come up with an equally annoying but effective solution. 
Hardcode "/mnt/sdcard" Yea, I said it.

Looks like someone else said it first ... [storing android application data on SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209469/storing-android-application-data-on-sd-card)

More joy... http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=414&t=7407