# How to replace a SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there a way to replace a complete SQLite DB?  I'm looking at building an app which holds a lot of data and I need to be able to update it.  Fortunately I am able to verify that the DB structure won't change, just the data.  Is there a clean way of doing this?

-- EDIT--

Apologies - I need to add more detail:

In order to update the data in the app, the plan is to just replace the DB which will be grabbed from a server somewhere.  So I won't be using the `onUpgrade` or adding data manually - I want to dump the existing file and copy a new file in to replace the old one.

I think a DB will normally be stored in "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/", do I have access to this directory?  In which case can I jst download the file from the server and copy it over the top (obviously making sure that nothing is accessing the file first etc)

Comment: Well, a SQLite database is just a file.  So, if you want to start with a new database, then start a new file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is the same as mine : [Can I download an SQLite db on /sdcard and access it from my Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055188/can-i-download-an-sqlite-db-on-sdcard-and-access-it-from-my-android-app)

```
File dbfile = new File("/sdcard/mydb.sqlite" ); 
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbfile, null);
System.out.println("Its open? "  + db.isOpen());
```

Answer (score 0):

in the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class is an `onUpgrade` method, and if a new Database Version is passed through the constructor that method is called.
In here you could drop the database and create a new one, or you could alter and create tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you're trying to do.

If the application is read-only and uses an SQLite database created outside the application then you can simply replace the SQLite database file.

If you want to replace individual *tables* within a database while leaving your applications writeable tables untouched, you can delete the data from the existing table and use INSERT INTO to get data from a different database.  You can also use the supplied command line tool and the ".import" command to load from CSV files.