# Use existing Database through sdcard in android

Tags: android

I have to make an application which is using `Sqlite` database. My problem is database size is too much for asset folder , so I have to put it in sdcard. I have tried it myself but unable to understand how to fetch data from it , cause whatever method I successfully implemented with the asset folder in previous app , they all are giving error like.

```
11-03 21:23:32.426: E/Database(13645): sqlite3_open_v2("/mnt/sdcard/myfolder/LeoTemplate.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
```

I have searched a lot , so please if anyone can suggest me tutorial or any other suggestion regarding only sdcard , it will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to create databaseHelper class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper then write down code for copying database into /data/data/package/databases as below..

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
      private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.project.examplepackage/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "mydatabase.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase; 
    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    /**
    * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
    * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
    */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet.
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(new File(database_path_to_sdcard));

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

        //Toast.makeText(myContext, "Copy Done", 300).show();
    }
```

**After creating this class write down this code for copying database into Application's launcher Activity.**

```
 DataBaseHelper myDBH = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        myDBH = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        try {
            myDBH.createDataBase();
            myDBH.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) {
             throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
```

**This way you can copy existing database from sdcard to your application 's database folder.**

Comment: thx. I am tring this. One question . Is it necessary to copy the database to /data/data/com.project.examplepackage/databases/ ? Cant we directly use external memory i.e. sdcard?

Comment: yes. you have to copy database into /data/data/package/databases folder.

Comment: or you can directly access from sdcard also

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055188/can-i-download-an-sqlite-db-on-sdcard-and-access-it-from-my-android-app.